# SQL Server job timeout

Tags: sql-server, timeout, scheduled-tasks

So, it seems that it is not possible to set the timeout for each single step in a SQL Server job ([article from StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200527/how-to-set-sql-server-2005-job-cmdexec-timeout)).

MSDN points out that you can of course set the Agent timeout:

- [Sql Server Agent properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189727.aspx).
- [Set Job execution shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190239.aspx).

**Questions**

1. How does Agent time-out work?
2. Is there any other way (preferably by configuration) to setup the single step timeout?
3. Is there any other way (preferably by configuration) to setup the whole job timeout?

Answer (score 3):

To answer question 2, I'm not sure if this is the best option but you could use OPENROWSET to control a single step timeout.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Just because OPENROWSET is *normally* used to access remote servers doesn't mean it has to be.

Probably this is similar to how agent timeout works.

You could even use this to control the whole job timeout although if you want to do it by configuration you'd have to create your own tables.

I'm not sure this is the best solution but it's a solution at least.